# Is this really the official website for DirectFB?

Tags: resources

The README document in the DirectFB source tarball lists the official website as [www.directfb.org](http://www.directfb.org); however, that site seems rather ... odd, to say the least. It starts off talking about Linux, but then goes off in quite a disturbing direction. Can I assume this is not the correct website for the DirectFB project (as opposed to the developer simply being a weirdo)?

If that is the case, does anyone know if there is a currently-maintained site anywhere for DirectFB? The Wikipedia article lists it as [www.directfb.net](http://www.directfb.net); however, that gives a DNS error.

Comment: Where did you find the DirectFB source tarball? (Just wondering if the site is self-referential)

Comment: Related (GitHub issue #4): https://github.com/DirectFB/directfb/issues/4  Issue #1 is also related: https://github.com/DirectFB/directfb/issues/1

Comment: @JeffSchaller I found it through a link on this LFS page: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/stable/basicnet/links.html, which links to the Fedora repository. So, it doesn't seem to give a clue about any official site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official web site used to be the .org site, but [the maintainer stopped paying the host fees](http://web.archive.org/web/20170603093935/http://directfb.net/) and the site was deleted in 2015. Someone else purchased the domain and the result is what you see today. In 2016 the maintainer set the site back up on http://www.directfb.net (with the listed URL at the top of the menu still the .org), and now that too has fallen off the Internet.

DirectFB is pretty much unmaintained now; [the last commit was in January 2014](https://github.com/DirectFB/directfb/commit/e97c8d40ae10585ad10cb55800efcd2ea13fbdf8) (at least on the GitHub mirror) and the last release was in February 2015.

Comment: Thanks for the info - I had suspected it might be the case. It might be a good idea then if someone could remove the references to that site in the README (and other docs).

Comment: @Time4Tea Submit a pull request to the project's GitHub.  Actually, someone already did that... https://github.com/DirectFB/directfb/pull/6

Comment: @Kusalananda ok, good that someone else spotted it too.